# Canvas.captureStream() does not exist in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, canvas, webrtc

I'm trying to send the content of an HTML canvas as a stream using webrtc.

While in pure HTML + JS I can use  `Canvas.captureStream()` to get an output stream, it seems like I can't find any way to do it using Angular 8.
The code I'm using is:

```
  @ViewChild('canvas', {static: true})
  canvas: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>;

  private canvasContext: CanvasRenderingContext2D;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.setupWebRtc();
    this.canvasContext = this.canvas.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
  }

  draw() {
    if (this.drawOnTop) {
      this.canvasContext.fillStyle = '#27bae7';
      this.canvasContext.fillRect(0, 100, this.canvas.nativeElement.width, 50);

      // Trying to get an output stream
      let  streamdata =  this.canvas.nativeElement.captureStream();
      console.log(streamdata);
   }
```

Using canvas.nativeElemet or canvasContext didn't seem to help as both have no captureStream() function.

I was thinking about using `canvas.nativeElement.toDataURL();` but it seems like a bad approach.

I would love to get some suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the solution was a simple casting to `<Any>`. Meaning it was a typing issue.
I used:

```
const  streamdata = (this.canvas.nativeElement as any).captureStream();
```

To get the stream.